# How to start the REST API Browser in Confluence and Jira

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-rest-api, confluence-rest-api

Purportedly JIRA and Confluence are shipped with a **REST API Browser** tool

> Although the REST API Browser is included in JIRA Server, Confluence
>   Server and Stash instances by default, or any application with the
>   developer toolbox plugin, it is not available in Atlassian Cloud
>   applications.
>   https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/using-the-rest-api-browser/

Unfortunately Atlassian does provide information on how this tool can be started for example the URL for this particular tool.

How can I start this tool in JIRA and Confluence?

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have the necessary permissions to view it, here's how to find the REST API Browser:

- For Jira, go to *Cog > System > REST API Browser* (at the very bottom)
- For Confluence, *Cog > General configuration > REST API Browser*.

The URL for both is `<baseUrl>/plugins/servlet/restbrowser`.

Comment: Make sure that you have API Browser Add-ons installed - https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211542/atlassian-rest-api-browser?hosting=server&tab=overview

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

1. System
2. Add-ons
3. Type “Atlassian REST API Browser” in the search box.
4. Install
5. Then, as Ian indicated, it will be at the bottom left of the System tab.

Be careful when using the “browser”. You can directly impact the data in your application as you can test the post functions. It’s not just a browser.